# Is there an equivalent of the C# dollar ($) operator in Java?

Tags: java, c#, string, string-concatenation, readability

In C# there is the `$` operator for strings:

```charp
$"Some Text here with {aVariable}";
```

Is there a similar way of doing that in Java?

The current way I do this is:

```java
"Some Text here with " + aVariable;
```

Comment: There is no operator in java, but classes that do what you want: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Comment: JFYI _"So in C# there is the $ operator for strings (Ex. $"Some Text here with {Variable here}";"_ - is called string interpolation.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not actually an operator. If it were an operator, you could use it on a string variable to achieve the same result with the contents of the variable. You can't. It's just a different kind of string expression wher the `$` is part of the delimiters.

Comment: Not yet but there is a [JEP](https://openjdk.org/jeps/0) for something similar: [String Templates](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8273943).

Comment: alternatives (workaround?): `"Some Text here with %s".formatted(aVariable)`, `String.format("Some Text here with %s", aVariable)` or (kind of older) `MessageFormat.format("Some Text here with {0}", aVariable)`

Comment: Yea I knew about the String.format, and whatnots, it's similar to how you can do it in C++. I was just hoping that maybe someone knew of the same kind of way as it could be handled in C#. @GuruStron Thanks, I had no idea that it was called that. I just know practical uses for it xD